# Compile GLFW with Codeblocks and Cmake Linux

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

Hello i am new to linux and i use Mint 18.2
and  Codeblocks 13.12

I downloaded glfw source package from  http://www.glfw.org/download.html
and i used Cmake to make a Codeblocks project so when i open my Codeblocks project everything compiles fine and i can run the examples
***The problem is that no libglfw3.a or libglfw3.so is produced*** (i also searched manually and by locate)

Please correct me if i understood something wrong!

Heres how my project looks like:
[image]

What do i have to do to link my program with glfw?

**NOTE: i found the library it was in mybuildDirectory/src**

Answer (score 1):

I found the library!

It is in ***buildDirectory/src***